# How to get the url for my app services on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have developed a RESTFul API flask application which I need to make it always run on APP Services, I am abit confused how to get my app API URL, I am using gunicorn inside my python virtual environment

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 --timeout 600 access_layer.main:app
```

but not sure what is the public IP of my API which I can access through, there is a public URL for my application (app-services-virtual-aaddress-ip:9000) but when I use it I can't access my API by curl.

Comment: You can't expose services on any ports other than 80 or 443 in App Service.

Comment: I have ediited the command so instead of 9000, it runs the application on ports 80, and 443 and I did the same inside my flask application, but still I can't access my API, can someone give me a more detailed answer?